# Once WebSocket handshake is finished can normal HTTP protocol run on the same TCP connection?

Tags: websocket, hot-module-replacement

If it matters, I am asking for the HMR (hot module replacement) use case.

I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383042/does-websocket-use-the-same-tcp-connection-that-was-used-by-the-initial-http-for). My understanding is that WebSocket uses the same connection that was used during the handshake. My question is after that:

1. Can the client (browser) still send requests to the same server and same port after the WebSocket protocol starts?
2. If it can, will it be a different connection?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is YES and YES.

**TL;DR** 
After reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3401024/529187), I think I can answer my own question now.

A client can build as many connections to a server (to the limit that they can afford). There are always two ports involved in a connection - one at the server, and another at the client.

The server-side port is specified (and is known to the client). Clients open a temporary or dynamic port that lasts only as long as the connection is made.